# How to render at most 4 items in each row

Tags: css

So I have an api that fetches an array of games from the database. and I would like to render them in the front-end.

I want to make sure each line has at most 4 games. So if there is 10 games it would be something like this.

```
game  game  game  game
game  game  game  game
game  game
```

I have tried the following way:

```
 this.state.sports.map((item, idx) => {
  if((idx + 1) % 4 === 0){
    game_list.push(
      <div className="row">
        <div key={item.name} className='each-game' >
            {item.name} 
            <br/>
            <img src={item.image} height = "100" width="100" alt = 'Not available'/>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }else{
    game_list.push(
      <div key={item.name} className='each-game'>
        {item.name} 
        <br/>
        <img src={item.image} height = "100" width="100" alt = 'Not available'/>
      </div>
    )
  }
})

{ game_list }
```

css

```
.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

And I got

```
game game game game game game game game game game
```

Can someone help me to fix it or show me a better way to do it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you not use `display: grid;` and simply make it a 4 colums grid? If you cannot use display:grid please share your restrictions with us.

Comment: please share component html and sports array of objects, game_list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a react question, you can just add items without a row and set `flex-basis: 25%;`

To align the last row to the lset you can add 3 (or n-1 if your n is different) "dummy" items with height 0:

```css
.cont {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.each-game {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 25%;
}

.dummy {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 25%;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class='each-game'>game name</div>
  <div class='each-game'>game name</div>
  <div class='each-game'>game name</div>
  <div class='each-game'>game name</div>
  <div class='each-game'>game name</div>
  <div class='each-game'>game name</div>
  <div class='each-game'>game name</div>
  <div class='each-game'>game name</div>
  <div class='each-game'>game name</div>
  <div class='each-game'>game name</div>
  <div class="dummy"></div>
  <div class="dummy"></div>
  <div class="dummy"></div>
  <div>
```